# How do I get my virtual docker repo to pull my parent microsoft docker image via docker file?

Tags: docker, artifactory

So in my artifactory I created a virtual docker repo named "docker-base"

I then created a remote docker repo named "docker-microsoft"
The remote repository url is set to "https://mcr.microsoft.com"

I now add my remote repo in the virtual base repo.

Now in my virtual docker repo in artifactory, the url to file shows:
my-org.com/artifactory/docker-base/

In my dockerfile I had:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```

I changed this to:

```
FROM <my-org>.com/artifactory/docker-base/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```

on my machine I do a docker login to my artifactory repo and it is successful.

when I do docker-compose build I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for <my-org>.com/artifactory/docker-base/dotnet/sdk:6.0                           1.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for <my-org>.com/artifactory/docker-base/dotnet/sdk:6.0:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: <my-org>.com/artifactory/docker-base/dotnet/sdk:6.0: not found
```

So I do not think my setup is correct, I am just not sure where I am messing up.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using Repository Path Method.
The example of docker push or pull and login commands for the same methods are:

```
docker pull/push <Artifactory Host IP Address>/<REPOSITORY_KEY>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>

docker login -u <USER_NAME> -p <USER_PASSWORD> <Artifactory Host IP Address>
```

In your case, try changing this

```
FROM <my-org>.com/artifactory/docker-base/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```

To,

```
FROM <my-org>.com/docker-base/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
```